# Matching values in a list collection and values in the DataTable row in C#

Tags: c#, datatable, datarow, listcollectionview

Good day Coders

I would like to know is there a way of matching values from a list collection to a data table row. Currently I have this, that doesn't work. `Ref_Number` is the list collection and `dtRefNum` is the `DataTable` row

```
 int count = Ref_Number.Count > dtRefNum.Rows.Count ? dtRefNum.Rows.Count : Ref_Number.Count;
 for (int i = 0; i < count; i++ )
 {
     if (Ref_Number[i].ToString().Trim().Contains(dtRefNum.Rows[i].ToString().Trim()))
      {
           var refnum = Ref_Number[i].ToString().Trim();
           var fsdfsdf = dtRefNum.ToString().Trim();
      }
      else if (Ref_Number[i].ToString().Trim() == dtRefNum.Rows[i].ToString().Trim())
      {

      }
```

Comment: You may want to use linq

Comment: If the index number are the same then use index instead of name.  There is a datamapping property that can be used in the datatable but it is probably easier to just use the index number (column number).  I just usually use dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { a, b, c, d, e});

Comment: Thank you @Jimbot. Any suggestions how to go about it?

Comment: Define `doesn't work`.

Comment: The code does not go into the if statement and there are matching values. However, the code isn't broken thou @mjwills

Comment: It doesn't work because it's try to compare the nth element of the list with the nth element of the DataTable...

Answer (score 0):

You may want to try this,

```
//assumming Ref_Number is List<string>
    for (int i = 0; i < dtRefNum.Rows.Count; i++ )
     {
         if ((Ref_Number.Where(rn => rn.ToLower().Trim() == dtRefNum.Rows[i].ToString().ToLower().Trim()).Count()) > 0)
          {
               var refnum = Ref_Number[i].ToString().Trim();
               var fsdfsdf = dtRefNum.ToString().Trim();
          }
    }
```

Comment: Thank you @Jimbot for your response. It didn't work operator '>' cannot be applied to operands of type 'method group' and  ínt'

Comment: Well it's a method, i forgot the () ...fixed

Comment: It still skip the if statement so im assuming the code isnt working correctly

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what are you looking for but if you have more rows in the list than in the table, it's ok? I don't know.

If you want to use linq, but I think it's the same:

```
int i=0;
Ref_Number.foreach(oh => 
    {
        if (oh[i].ToString().Trim() = dtrefnum[i].ToString().Trim(); //or use contains whateveryouwant
            ...
    }
```